# Incremental React Game with setInterval: Cannot update during existing state transition

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to get this code working as a "incremental" game, where the options will be displayed after some credits, but Im getting the following warning (only once):

#### Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component.

index.js:2178 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state 
   transition (such as within `render` or another component's 
   constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and 
   state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved 
   to `componentWillMount`.

#### Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grid, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";

class EventDashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state={
      credits: 0,
      newOption: false,
      newOptionDirty: false,
    }
    this.addCredits = this.addCredits.bind(this)
    this.renderNewOption = this.renderNewOption.bind(this)
    this.intervalID = null;
  }

  addCredits() {
    this.setState((previousState) => ({
      credits: previousState.credits + 1
    }))
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      this.addCredits()
    }, 1000)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalID);
  }

  renderNewOption() {
    if(this.state.credits === 5 && !this.state.newOptionDirty) {
      // the warning happens here
      this.setState(() =>({
        newOptionDirty: true
      }))
    }
    if(this.state.newOptionDirty) {
      return(
        <div>
          <Button> Add new feature </Button>
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div>no options until 5 credits</div>
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Grid.Column width={10}>
          <Button
            onClick={this.addCredits}
          >AddCredits</Button>

          {this.renderNewOption()}

        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column width={6}>
          <h1>Credits</h1>
          <h2>{this.state.credits}</h2>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}

export default EventDashboard
```

In spite of this warning everything is working fine.

What good practice Im missing?

Comment: Which `setState` triggers your warning? When does it happen?

Comment: It happens at the moment the credits achieves the 5 value. So it happens in the renderNewOption method.

Comment: Oh, I see now..

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, working on an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed with your `renderNewOption()` method and how you use it.

You are invoking `renderNewOption()` from `render()`, which is bad because you are doing a `setState()` in it. Remember that whenever you do `setState()` you update the state and trigger a new render. As such, having `setState()` inside the `render()` would create an infinite loop since the render function would keep calling itself.

In this particular case, you won't actually get an infinite loop because you have an `if`-case that prevents that, however your component will run it the first time (when `newOptionDirty` is still `false`). When that happens, your component hasn't mounted yet because the `render()` never finished before the this particular `setState()` was invoked.

***TL;DR:*** Never call `setState()` during a render.

---

Try this instead:

```
componentDidMount() {
  setInterval(() => {
    this.addCredits()
  }, 1000);
}

addCredits() {
  this.setState((previousState) => ({
    credits: previousState.credits + 1
  });
}

renderNewOption() {
  if(this.state.credits >= 5) {
    return(
      <div>
        <Button> Add new feature </Button>
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <div>no options until 5 credits</div>
    )
  }
}
```

We don't need (and shouldn't) to create some new state variable inside the render. All we are interested in is if `credits` are equal to `5` or not.

Depending on its value, we return the appropriate React Element (button or no button).

Comment: @LucasOliveiraSilva, alright. Check the updated answer.

Comment: It's not stopping the timer. I removed that bit. You are correct that an infinite loop won't happen, but it's still 100% bad practice to have your `setState` there. Your dirty variable is also unnecessary, all you are interested in is if your credits are == 5 or not.

Comment: It solve the problem, but does not explain how I can use the setState to change the state when some criteria is reached. What if I need to change the state as soon as I achieve 100 credits to do something else, for example?

Comment: @LucasOliveiraSilva, then just add another `else if` in `renderNewOption` :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are doing any asynchronous stuff in your component like callbacks/Promises/setTimeout you might run into a situation when a component might have already been unmounted and you will try to update umounted component ( like in your case ) which might lead to memory leaks. This is one of the use cases for external state management libraries and middlewares like redux and redux-saga/redux-observable.

If you are going to do it in your components however you need to take care to do necessary cleanups when component unmounts. This is what for `componentWillUnmount` is used for:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  ...
  this.intervalID = null;
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    this.addCredits()
  }, 1000)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.intervalID);
}
```

Comment: Ok well pointed. However it does not solve the original problem. I will edit the code to add this very good practice.